# How to DM all server members discord(js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**I want to try and dm all server members using a discord bot with this code:**

```js
if (message.content === 'tdmall') {


    const members = async function() {

        message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).array();

        let undelivered = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {

            const member = members[i];

            await member.send('Hello there.')
                .catch(() => undelivered++);
        }

        message.channel.send(`Messages sent. ${undelivered} members couldn't receive it.`)

            .catch(console.error);

    }
}
```

**My bot doesn't dm every server member, but no error is logged either so can you help me?**

*this is an edited version as i followed someone's advice*

Comment: As the error suggests, you need to run that code in an async function like `async function(...) { /*Your code*/ }`

Comment: Should note this is against TOS, why not just ping everyone?

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the asynchronous function, but you're not actually invoking it. Add `await members();` after your declaration, as such:

```js
if (message.content === 'tdmall') {

    // Declare function
    const messageAllMembers = async function() {

        message.guild.members.filter(m => !m.user.bot).array();

        let undelivered = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {

            const member = members[i];

            await member.send('Hello there.')
                .catch(() => undelivered++);
        }

        message.channel.send(`Messages sent. ${undelivered} members couldn't receive it.`)

            .catch(console.error);

    }

    // Invoke function
    await messageAllMembers();
}
```